# How can I use django to display data on a website without reloading the whole page

Tags: javascript, django

i use django to render a page.
If a user now requests information, I would like to load it from the database and display it on the website. It's actually quite simple. I get the information in Django and I find the data in the database. BUT how do I get them back to the user. I don't want to re-render the whole page (it could) I just want to re-render part of the website without having to reload the whole page. Is there a trick?
I might have thought of sending the data back via AJAX and adjusting the page using js, but isn't there a more elegant option from django and is AJAX still up to date? had heard that this should no longer be used ...

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do this with django out of the box. You can achieve this using `django-channels` and a client side app that connect to the websocket.

If you need help with this, try to watch and follow this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RVH05S1qab8

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are confused by the term: The 'X' in AJAX stands for XML, which has been replaced by JSON as the standard format for the data being exchanged between server and client in AJAX calls. But that's just a detail and AJAX is still an important concept implemented on most dynamic web pages.

Now, to this part of your question:

> I might have thought of sending the data back via AJAX and adjusting
> the page using js, but isn't there a more elegant option

Yes, manipulating the DOM 'by hand' after an AJAX request was what web developers usually did before JavaScript frameworks like React or Vue were developed. These are your more elegant options compared to jQuery or plain JavaScript.

One more thing: You might have heard of WebSockets. This is another standard for communication between servers and client. It has it's advantages in certain use cases, but is unlikely to replace AJAX. As a beginner web developer, start learning AJAX.